# Have Elite Dangerous use Stereo instead of Hands-Free?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-odyssey

When I start Elite Dangerous: Odyssey, it automatically switches to using the [Hands-Free AG Audio output instead of using the Stereo (A2DP)](https://superuser.com/questions/1088942/whats-the-difference-between-stereo-and-hands-free) one. How do I make it use the Stereo one? The Hands-Free AG sounds horrible.

Comment: I don't have a bluetooth headphone to test with, but I imagine the solution will be something akin to disabling it on the device itself. Does anything like this help? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/fix-for-bluetooth-headphones-or-speaker-using/7023c43b-c001-42e9-9ec9-95a8f96a4b4c#:~:text=Open%20Devices%20and%20Printers%20from,free%20Telephony%20and%20click%20OK

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1036379/bluetooth-headphones-uncheck-handsfree-telephony-profile-did-not-work